# Drop a Page/Layer from Tiff/SVS File

Tags: c#, tiff, libtiff.net

Is there an easy way to remove/drop a layer/page/directory from a tiff/svs file in C#?  I am looking to remove a specific page from a series of tiff/svs files that is simple.  It would be nice if it were something like `tifFile.dropLayer(0)` rather than needing to copy everything from within to a copy.  I have tried LibTiff for a good solution, but that is more complicated than I would prefer.  I tried using their `UnlinkDirectory()` method, but the layer still shows after the fact (unless there is a save call or something I am missing.  For that, I was doing:

```
using (Tiff tif = Tiff.Open(fileName, "a"))
{tif.UnlinkDirectory(4);}
```

I thought that it saved and wrote on the `Close()` method and that got invoked on `Dispose()`.  I just need a simple open source library or some other way in .NET to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a resolution to my problem.  I was using a nuget package version of the LibTiff library.  I uninstalled it, cloned their repo from Github, copied the necessary projects from that repo into my project, and things worked correctly.

I am still using the same basic code as above except I am directly calling `Flush` on the `Tiff` object rather than waiting for the `Write`, `Close`, or `Dispose` methods to do it for me.  I still tried `Flush` with the nuget version before switching the source.

It seems that the problem was with either a corrupt nuget install of the package or something else in the ether.